# When do pushouts along epis preserve products?

Tags: ct.category-theory

A pushout diagram in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a commutative square with a certain universal property; as usual, say that the pushout diagram is *along an epi* if at least one of the two arrows out of its source object is an epi.

Assuming $\mathcal{C}$ has products, then given two pushout diagrams $D_1,D_2$, their product is a commutative square, but not generally a pushout diagram. What if we additionally assume that $D_1$ and $D_2$ are each along an epi?

Of course, we do not expect the result to be a pushout diagram in an arbitrary $\mathcal{C}$, but are there nice cases where we do expect this?

**Question:** Is there any well-known sort of category $\mathcal{C}$ for which pushout-along-epis commutes with finite products?

A special case of the above question was considered in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77498/the-binary-product-preserves-pushouts), where Todd Trimble showed that it holds.

Comment: Doesn't Todd's argument work in any $\infty$-pretopos?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, and unfortunately, this doesn't even seem to be the case in Set unless both legs of the span are epic. I didn't notice this at first because I was working in vector spaces, which have biproducts!