# Finite homotopy limits commute with sequential homotopy colimits

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I would like to know for what kind of model category finite homotopy limits commute with sequential homotopy colimits. Would cofibrantly generated and finitely locally presentable be enough? It seems to be true in simplicial sets.

I found a proof of something close in Stephan Schwede's paper "Spectra in model categories and applications to the algebraic cotangent complex", but I wasn't able to deduce the statement above from his.
Jacob Lurie has a proof of the analogous statement for colimits and limits of quasi-categories, in "Higher topos theory".

Anything related would be much appreaciated!

Comment: I bet you need a combinatorial finely presentable model category.

Comment: From what I could see by googling around, I bet you're right. I'm afraid this could mean that the proof is very indirect... By the way what does finely mean?

Comment: Probably "finitely presentable". The corresponding statement is true for ordinary categories, i.e. in a locally finitely presentable category, sequential (indeed, filtered) colimits preserve finite limits.

Comment: Yes, finely = finitely + an old Android version

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Can you please provide a reference for that result?

Comment: It's well known for $\mathbf{Set}$, so we can deduce the same for presheaf toposes. Now use the fact that any locally finitely presentable category admits a _reflective_, fully faithful embedding into a presheaf topos that preserves filtered colimits. (See e.g. Theorem 1.39 in [_Locally presentable and accessible categories_], or Theorem 5.2.7 in [_Handbook of categorical algebra_, Vol. 2].)

Comment: What do you mean by "finite homotopy limit"? If you mean a homotopy limit indexed by an ordinary category with finitely many morphisms, it is not true even in spaces. Take $S^1 \subset S^2 \subset \cdots$ each with the antipodal action of $\mathbb{Z}/2$. Taking homotopy fixed points of the action gives the empty set in each case (the homotopy fixed points are sections of $S^n \to \mathbb{R}{P}^n \to \mathbb{R}{P}^{\infty} = B \mathbb{Z}/2$), but for the sequential homotopy colimit $S^\infty$, which is contractible, taking homotopy fixed points gives a one point space.

Comment: On the other hand, homotopy limits indexed by simplicial sets with finitely many nondegenerate simplices do commute with filtered homotopy colimits in spaces. (Notice that while $\mathbb{Z}/2$ thought of as a category with a single element has only finitely many morphisms, what matters here is that its nerve has infinitely many nondegenerate simplices.)

Comment: Just to be explicit about something that does work in "ordinary" diagrams: for spaces, homotopy limits indexed by *graphs* with finitely many arrows do commute with filtered homotopy colimits. (Another way to describe them is as homotopy limits indexed by finite *free* categories.)

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena What about the free category on the graph with a loop, i.e. the additive monoid of $\mathbb{N}$ thought of as a category?

Comment: That one's fine too, @ZhenLin, even though it doesn't have finitely many morphisms as a category. It's funny that a category C is filtered if and only if colimits of shape C commute with finite limits in Set, but it is not true that a category C has finitely ,any morphisms if and only if limits of shape C commutes with filtered colimits in Set. The first example beyond finite categories I noticed was $\mathbb{N}$, then finitely generated monoids, and then I asked this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140158/which-limits-commute-with-filtered-colimits-in-the-category-of-sets

Comment: I realize now that by talking about ordinary limits it may have sounded like I wasn't answering your question, @ZhenLin: it is also true that $\mathbb{N}$-shaped homotopy limits commute with filtered homotopy colimits in spaces.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: Thanks a lot for your comments! I am interested in homotopy limits over posets, I'm happy with categories with finite nerves. It seems to me that one should use Dugger's theorem to reduce the question for a general finite locally presentable cpctly gen model cat to simplicial sets. Do you know of a reference for simplicial sets? Can one deduce it from Lurie's proof for infinity categories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In combinatorial model categories finite limits commute with (sufficiently large) filtered homotopy colimits. Suppose, for simplicity, that the combinatorial model category is simplicial and generating cofibrations have $\lambda$-presentable domain and codomain. In this case $\lambda$-filtered colimits are homotopy colimits. Suppose, in addition, that the underlying locally presentable model category is $\lambda$-locally presentable. Then $\lambda$-filtered colimits commute with $\lambda$-small limits. Finite limits are $\lambda$-small for all $\lambda$.

Lets say that the category $J$ indexing the homotopy limit is finite if it has finitely many objects and morphisms, and the diagram $EJ$ of simplicial sets serving as a cofibrant replacement of the constant diagrams of points indexed by $J$ in the projective model structure on ${\cal S}^J$ has a finite simplicial set in each entry. For example, a finite group is not a finite category by this definition. A finite homotopy limit is a homotopy limit over a finite diagram.

Suppose that $\cal M$ is a simplicial $\lambda$-combinatorial model category and $F\colon J\to \cal M$ a finite diagram. Then $\mathrm{holim}_J F$ may be computed as a weighted limit with the weight $EJ$, in other words this is an end construction:
$$
\mathrm{holim}_J F = \mathrm{hom}(EJ, F),
$$
which is a finite weighted limit commuting with $\lambda$-filtered colimits, hence, commuting with $\lambda$-filtered homotopy colimits. In particular, if $\lambda=\aleph_0$, then filtered homotopy colimits commute with finite homotopy limits.

Comment: Boris, is really necessary that the category be cofibrant?

Comment: Of cause not, Fernando, cofibrant generation is a luxury. We just need it to compare the homotopy filtered colimits with the strict filtered colimits. For this purpose it suffices to assume that trivial fibrations are closed under $\lambda$-filtered colimits. But I'd rather keep this answer less technical.

Comment: Sorry, Boris, I meant simplicial, not cofibrant. I don't know why I wrote cofibrant.

Comment: No, this assumption can also be removed using a framing and applying the respective formulas from Hirschhorn's book for the computation of homotopy limits. Alternatively we can replace our combinatorial model category by a simplicial one in a homotopy meaningful way and conclude that finite homotopy limits commute with filtered homotopy colimits since they commute in the simplicial replacement.

Comment: Boris, thanks for your answer. If $\lambda$ is bigger than $\aleph_0$, is it then not true in general that sequential homotopy colimits commute with finite homotopy limits? (thanks for clarifying what finite means in this context)

Comment: I think that you are right. In a more general situation it is probably possible to find a counterexample, but every combinatorial model category is Quillen equivalent, by a theorem of Dugger, to a left Bousfield localization of simplicial presheaves over some small category equipped with the projective model structure. But in such categories generating cofibrations are the same as the projective generating cofibrations. In particular, they have $\aleph_o$-presentable domains and codomains.