# Which limits distribute over which colimits in $Set$? How about in $Spaces$?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, limits-and-colimits

I've never really thought much about [distributivity of limits and colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributivity+of+limits+over+colimits) -- I tend to think more about [commutativity of limits and colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutativity+of+limits+and+colimits). [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383186/commutation-of-limits-and-colimits-is-there-a-choice-diagram) makes me want to change that.

The question of [which limits commute with which colimits in the category of sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93262/which-colimits-commute-with-which-limits-in-the-category-of-sets?) has a complicated answer, but important special cases which are not so complicated. This leads to the title question:

**Question:**

1. Which limits distribute over which colimits in the 1-category $Set$?
2. Which limits distribute over which colimits in the $\infty$-category $Spaces$?

Is it complicated like with commutativity? Or is it maybe simpler? If it's complicated, are there good simplifying assumptions one can make?

Comment: Does the general definition of distribution of limits and colimits appear in the literature, or just on the nlab?

Comment: I’m looking for something similar. I am currently trying to understand the general nLab statement for what distributivity would mean if K is a functor out of I, but then there is the second question of am I even in the context where such distributivity holds!

Comment: @cheyne At this point I've talked to quite a few people about this and everyone has the same reaction: the notion on the nlab seems very interesting, but frustrating and difficult to actually get one's head around and seems to be kind of an "orphan" -- no literature discussing the topic. One place where this notion _is_ discussed is around 7.11 in [Chu and Haugseng](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.03977); the discussion there was inspired by the nlab apparently.